# Structuring NDB models to make an "antijoin" query possible

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to have a recommendation API for my app where a user can get a suggestion for an object they **haven't** yet seen, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I'm supposed to structure my data to make such a query efficient.

Here's an example using books. Suppose this is what I have as my models, the most normalized way possible:

```
def User(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

def Book(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty()

def Review(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.KeyProperty(User)
  book = ndb.KeyProperty(Book)
  stars = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  text = ndb.TextProperty()
```

Now given a user, I want to retrieve a book that the user hasn't reviewed and this seems basically impossible to do efficiently and at scale (e.g. 50k users, 100k books).

I've read around and I realize that I should denormalize my data somehow, but for the life of me, I can't figure out a good way to do it. I've thought of putting `Review` as a `StructuredProperty` inside of `Book`, but I don't think that really buys me very much, and it means that I'll be limited by the number of reviews I can add to a book (because of the size limit for entries).

The other things I've seen mentioned a lot when other people asked similar questions are ancestors and `ComputedProperty`, but I don't really see how they help me here either.

Surely it's not actually impossible, and I just have a weak understanding of the best practices, right?

Comment: If the books use the ISBN as the key, then you could just store 13digit numbers rather than the full key as per @Alex 's answer and not storing the full key means you could store even more books that have been  reviewed ;-)  Alternately allocate a sequential id for every book, then keep a bitmap of all books read for each user.  Then you only need 125000 bytes to track 1million books.  You could then randomly choose a bit position not set, and perform a < or > book number and grab the next found book in that interval.

Comment: The bitmap idea is super nifty, I'll keep it in mind for the future. Unfortunately, I don't have a natural id space and I suspect that allocating sequential ids is going to give me a lot of trouble down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful de-normalization might be to add to `User` the list of books they've reviewed:

```
def User(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  seen = ndb.KeyProperty('Book', repeated=True)
```

and to 'Book' an overall "score" whereby you'll want to order queries:

```
def Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    score = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

as usual the cost of de-normalization comes when **writing** -- in addition to creating a new review you'll also need to update the `User` and `Book` entities (and you may need a transaction, thus, entity groups, if e.g several users may be reviewing a book at the same time, but I'm skipping that part:-).

The advantage is that, when needing to propose a new book to a given User, you can query for Book (keys-only, sorted by score), with a cursor (or just a loop on the query) to "page through" the query's results, and just reject keys that, as you can check in-memory, are already in the given User's `seen` property.

Upon getting the User entity for the purpose, you can turn the `seen` into a `set`, so the checks will be very fast.  This assumes that a user won't review more than a few thousand books, so everything needed **should** nicely fit in memory...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Would I be able to get away with storing just the numeric ids that are generated for the keys as an ndb.IntegerProperty()? I guess that would give me a bit of space savings.

Comment: @KirillLevin, yes, you could indeed save a minute amount of space that way (at the expense of a little bit more processing to prepare the `seen` set or extract the books' ids from their keys after the keys-only query).